# rails render json returns array instead of dictionary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

If I have a standard Post resource (model) and in my index action have:

```
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
    render json: @posts
  end
```

and there's only 1 post in @posts, I get back something like

```
[{"id": 1, "title":"ImaPost"}]
```

but I (think I) want to get back something more like

```
{"posts": ["Post":{"id": 1, "title":"ImaPost"}]}
```

The reason I am trying to do this is because I am follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ixk93yx-v28) for using an api with swift for iOS dev, but it's my first time creating an API and its my first time using something like this with swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  render json: {posts: @posts}
end
```

Comment: I realized that json is fine as an array or as a dictionary. For the record your post will create a dictionary {"posts": [{"id": 1, "title": "imatitle"}]} which is actually still slightly different from the {"posts": [{"Post": {"id": 1, title: "imatitle"}}]} that I was actually looking for. That's ok though, I didn't realize that I could just as easily treat it as an array.